# How to set the backgroundcolor of BottomTabNavigator to transparent? without using position: 'absolute'

Tags: react-navigation

I'm trying to make the background of my BottomTabNavigator transparent.

I've tried setting the position to 'absolute', this makes the background transparent but now the tab bar is not clickable anymore. Does anyone knows a solution?

```
tabBarOptions: {
        inactiveBackgroundColor : COLORS.TINTCOLOR,
        activeBackgroundColor: COLORS.TINTCOLOR,
        activeTintColor: COLORS.WHITE,
        inactiveTintColor: COLORS.WHITE,
        showLabel: false,
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12
        },
        style: {
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            borderTopColor: COLORS.TINTCOLOR,
            height: 50,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
            borderTopRightRadius: 25,
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried updating to latest version?

Comment: Yes, but this didn't work either..